# Sound Echo on Remote Desktop using local headset

Tags: audio, remote-desktop, skype

I work from home on a windows 7 PC and connect through (using remote desktop) to my work computer which is windows 10. I've setup my local headset to be used with Skype/Teams which runs on my work computer but for some reason the person on the other end of the call is getting their voice echoed back to them. For me the call quality is fine and my voice doesn't echo back but at the moment it is not usable as the other caller is constantly getting echo back. Does anybody know what this might be?

On my local machine, I have a bluetooth headset, and in the RDC settings I have Play on this computer and record from this computer selected.

On my work computer I had to manually change the fDisableAudioCapture to 0 in order for my machine to pic up the local microphone.

If i use teams/skype on my local machine it's all fine, the problem seems to be relaying the sound back when connecting remotely.

Any help would be appreciated as it's very annoying:)